# Slick slider is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I am trying to implement slick slider into my website, but it's not working. I revised so many times, trying to figure out what is wrong but couldn't find anything, I am getting crazy! Please help me out to find an issue. Thank you, Marko.

```
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

    <title>Gamer World News Entertainment</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="slick">
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
        <div>your content</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-F0O1TmEa4I8N24nY0bya59eP6svWcshqX1uzwaWC4F4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slick').slick({
        lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      });
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you get the slider to work with just jQuery and the slick library (in case the other files may be causing some sort of conflict)?  Take a peak at the console to see if any errors are popping up (web developer tools / f12)

Comment: I inspected in Chrome dev tools and there is no any error.

Here is my codepen: 

https://codepen.io/mstorne/project/editor/ABBYEm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's working, you're just showing as many slides as there are elements. Turn on infinite mode or use more elements in your slider.

Answer (score 0):

add another element on your slider and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error in developer tools? if there is no error in loading slick files then

change slidesToShow: 1 in your code and try. this is absolutely working fine for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slick').slick({
     lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1 ,
    dots:true
  });
});
```

for better visibility i have included dots:true. even without this it works fine.in this case we have to drag the slides.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got it done, I supposed to add another element into slider. I didn't even think about it. 
Thank you guys very much.